# Is there a platform-independent way to check if a file path is some representation of a root directory in Haskell?

Tags: linux, windows, haskell, path

In Haskell, is there a portable way to check of a `FilePath` if it’s a root directory, e.g. `/` or `//` on Unix/POSIX/Linux, and `C:\` or `\\?\UNC\Foobar` on Windows/NT/DOS? I’ve checked through the `directory` and `filepath` packages but I can’t find a function for this.

Comment: If `\\?\UNC\Foobar\Share` is a root directory, would a mount point like `/proc` be as well?

Comment: @thatotherguy sorry, I fixed that. I mean \\?\UNC\Foobar.

Comment: More specifically, I mean a path that can’t be reduced further while still referring to something at all. `/proc` can definitely be reduced to `/`, `/` itself can’t.

Comment: "Can't be reduced" doesn't quite match up to the concept of a root. A relative path like `foo` can't be reduced either, without first making it absolute, but it's not a root.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't see anything in `base`, but there appears to be a [`filepath`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/filepath-1.4.2.2) library that claims to be shipped with GHC (and indeed I find it available even in a project with no dependencies). It contains functions such as [`isDrive :: FilePath -> Bool`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/filepath-1.4.2.2/docs/System-FilePath-Windows.html#v:isDrive). It notes that on POSIX, `/` is considered the only "drive". This function appears to behave the way you hope (scroll up to the docs for [`splitDrive`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/filepath-1.4.2.2/docs/System-FilePath-Windows.html#v:splitDrive) for examples involving UNC).